# Javascript check if the sum of object values is equal to 0

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sum

I have a dictionary containing keys and values shown beneath.

[image: image of dict]

I wish for an alert to appear if all of the values (the sum of all) within the dictionary are equal to one.

I am very new to JavaScript but have managed to come up with the code beneath. It is not working but I think I am on the correct lines.

```
 for (lstLength.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (sum(lstLength[key]] == 0)){
        window.alert("no data!")
    }
 }
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The `for-loop` does — not — do like you think. [I guess you mean the `for...in` loop.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` to convert the object into array. Use `reduce` to sum the values.

Like:

```
Object.values(lstLength).reduce((c, v) => c + v, 0)
```

Sample code: (with values)

```js
let lstLength = {
  'property1': 3,
  'property2': 4,
  'property3': 5,
  'property4': 6,
};

if (Object.values(lstLength).reduce((c, v) => c + v, 0) == 0) console.log('no data!')
else console.log('with data!')
```

Sample code: (without values)

```js
let lstLength = {
  'property1': 0,
  'property2': 0,
  'property3': 0,
  'property4': 0,
};

if (Object.values(lstLength).reduce((c, v) => c + v, 0) == 0) console.log('no data!')
else console.log('with data!')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var sum = 0;
 for (lstLength.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    sum += Number(lstLength[key])
 }
 if (sum == 0)){
    window.alert("no data!")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a *for in*

```
let lstLength = {
  'propA': 0,
  'propB': 0,
};

sum = 0
for (prop in lstLength) {
  sum += lstLength[prop]
}

if (sum === 0) {
  alert('empty list')
} else {
  alert('valid list')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to sum just to check whether there is data or not

```
if(Math.max(...Object.values(lstLength)) === 0) {
    window.alert("no data!");
}
```